# How can I find the entry point for a Python Application I have in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am clicking on run inside of the IDE.  Here's the code for run:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail ${SHELLFLAGS}

make -C $(dirname $0) run RUNFLAGS="$*"
```

It start up my application.

But I would like to try and debug and it does not seem to be stopping at any of the places where I place a breakpoint.

In PyCharm, where would be the first python code entered after clicking on the file called run?

Comment: From what you've posted, it's not possible to tell.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's all I have to go by.  I'm very new to Python.  How is it normally decided which .py file will run first from PyCharm?

Comment: What you posted is a bash script that sets an environment variable and then starts a make - without the `makefile`, it's impossible to tell what we're even talking about. Maybe you could get an answer if you share the `makefile`, but it's possibly the Python script you expect to be run gets accessed even deeper in. I think it's clear you did not create this setup - I would recommend asking someone who did about an explanation or documentation. By the way, none of this really has anything to do with PyCharm specifically.